# Basic camera in app

Tags: android

I am just trying to activate the camera in my app I have done the following and kept it as simple as possible.

**AndroidManifest file**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
...
    <activity
        android:name=".CameraAct"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

**CameraAct.class**

```
   public class CameraAct extends AppCompatActivity {

       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);

        // do we have a camera?
        if (!getPackageManager()
                .hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "No camera on this device", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        } else {
            cameraId = findFrontFacingCamera();
            if (cameraId < 0) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "No front facing camera found.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                camera = Camera.open(cameraId);
            }
          }
       }

       private int findFrontFacingCamera() {
          int cameraId = -1;
          // Search for the front facing camera
          int numberOfCameras = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
          for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCameras; i++) {
             CameraInfo info = new CameraInfo();
             Camera.getCameraInfo(i, info);
             if (info.facing == CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
                Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "Camera found");
                cameraId = i;
                break;
            }
          }
        return cameraId;
    }
```

**activity_camera.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

</RelativeLayout>
```

The activity opens and on the log the I see the `debug_tag`: Camera found in logcat however I dont see the camera on the screen. This is what I see when the activity launches:
[image]

Comment: Can you share your activity_camera.xml?

Comment: Do you have any RunTime exception? Camera.open(int) Creates a new Camera object to access a particular hardware camera. If the same camera is opened by other applications, this will throw a RuntimeException.

You must call release() when you are done using the camera, otherwise it will remain locked and be unavailable to other applications.

Comment: If using Android 6.0, check the policy manager and make sure you have permission to access it. This can be done in run time too.

Comment: You seem to have missed out the code for adding surfaceview and adding the camera to the surfaceview. Before that are you building a custom camera application or you are trying to capture a picture or video?

Comment: I am trying to create use the camera as a background to a menu that I have. Not capturing or anything fancy, as a start I want to get the camera to work